# In React Native cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I have a project in `react-native`. When I run `react-native run-ios` on the mac terminal, I get this error:

`Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots: [path to root]`

I don't know what that means. Please can someone clarify this for me. 
I can see `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` in the root folder, I have a folder called `app` in which there is a `index.js`, do I have to add that `index.js` in the project root folder?

I'm running on:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3
node 6.9.1
npm 3.10.8
```

Comment: I got this issue when I downgrade the react-native version. Nowhere i was using index.js in my code. Tested by adding index.js and it works but why?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this either it is not your project or you didn't create it with the right tools.

If this is just your project and never worked, make sure you create it with the 'init' command with react-native. Usually projects do not have another index.js.

Another issue could be that your index.ios.js points to a not existing index.js

Comment: On the spot! It's not my project, it's one of my client's project. But it's too big to start the whole thing and with deadlines a bit tight. I'll check what you said about `index.ios.js`. Thanks for your response though!!

Comment: @Shaoz Another issue could be that iOS code is hardcoded into reading the index.js file directly which won't exist if you didn't bundle the project first. Open the AppDelegate.m file and see if you can find any reference to that file.

Comment: thanks for your response, but the `index.ios.js` is not pointing to any `index.js` at all. Something else is happening but don't know what it is... And I'm not familiar with AppDelegate.m (don't know Swift at all), please where would I find any reference or what does it look like?

Comment: Just open xCode and you can find the file in the navigator tree on the left. There won't be too many files in a basic project so you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has inconsistently happened for my colleagues, who all followed my instructions for setting up an RN dev env, but not for me. What would happen for them is their initial build would work, particularly if iOS or Android native files were being built from scratch but the subsequent builds would result in the dreaded error from the bundler:

`error: bundling failed: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file artifacts/index.js in any of the roots`

Today we noticed that 'which watchman' returns nothing for them but returned an instance of watchman for me. When I setup my dev env a year ago I installed watchman but did not include it in my instructions for the setup of their dev environments.

Installing watchman (and ensuring it is in the path) took care of this for my colleagues. On a Mac you can install via 'brew install watchman' if using HomeBrew.  There are other options for installation of watchman: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/

Copied from my reply to a GitHub issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246#issuecomment-377302492

Answer (score -2):

When you use react-native-cli, you don't have index.js. But the index.js is generated when you use the create-react-native-app

Comment: If `react-native-cli` doesn't have `index.js` why is it asking for it? So does that mean, I have to create a `index.js` file in the root? What is the solution?